# Buildpacks error

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops, ibm-cloud-tools

I am running an application at IBM Bluemix DevOps and while deploying I am getting this error:

[image: this]

> App staging failed in the buildpack compile phase.

On checking logs I found this:
[image: Logs]

How do I get rid of this problem?

Comment: In the top right corner of your screenshot, click on the 4rth icon to view logs.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the Github project or sample application, if you are using one?

Comment: @RamVennam Thanks Ram. I checked my log and have put a screenshot of it in my original question. Possible problem it says is :- Gulp may not be tracked in package.json !!!

Comment: @HobertBushIII I am not following a particular sample but i am taking major references from this https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/car-dashboard

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use a node npm module which you might not have declared as a dependency. Add gulp to your package.json as show in in the car-dashboard sample you are referencing.

Comment: I already have added gulp in my package.json, but it still says "gulp may not be tracked" :(